# Setting up sendgrid for rails..returning Authorization error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, ssmtp

The emails now send from my local, but do not send from my box. I am returned this error. Anyone know what this might be?

Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
):

My environments/production.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port => '25',
  :domain => "mydomain.com",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => "email@gmail.com",
  :password => "password1234"
 }
```

/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf :

```
root=postmaster
mailhub=smtp.sendgrid.net
AuthUser=email@gmail.com
AuthPass=password1234
AuthMethod=LOGIN
rewriteDomain=mydomain.com
FromLineOverride=YES
UseSTARTTLS=NO
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This usually happens because your account hasn't been provisioned.

Comment: So how do you get an account provisioned? Don't just state the problem, find a solution.

Comment: Here's how you provision your account on heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid#provisioning-the-add-on

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I find that it's more favourable to use PostFix with SendGrid so there is less delay for the user when they are using your rails app. When I was using SMTP (like you have above), I was getting long delays when loading an action that sent mail. 
See this SendGrid wiki page for more info: 
http://wiki.sendgrid.com/doku.php?id=postfix

Answer (score 0):

When registering to SendGrid it will be moderated by admin before you can send mail from new account.

See:
https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/200181628

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my test server and due to inactivity, the account was disabled. I created a Support ticket with SendGrid and it was reactivated.